# What corresponds to the "Gson Annotation" in Azure table CRUD?

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services, gson

I created a **Azure mobile app** 
and did the Quick Start TodoItem tutorial successfully ,
but I still have a ton of problems.

[image]

This is what I see in the ToDoItem object,
There is **Gson Annotations** with each of property,
and I'm wondering **what is the annotation value according to** ???

The column name in the Table ? Nope , In the table I used the uppercase in the first word like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET service uses a standard JSON serializer to serialize the objects from the server.  The standard serializer lower-cases the first letter, so `Complete` becomes `complete` and `MyCustomVar` becomes `myCustomVar`.

On the client, semantics differ between platforms.  Sometimes the conversion is done for you (.NET), sometimes it is handled as is (JavaScript) and sometimes you need annotations (Android).  The annotations for Android turn the internal representation `mComplete` into the wire-form (`complete`) so that they match.